# How to: MySQL order by user_id (RAND) with pagination

Tags: php, mysql, session, random, sql-order-by

Looking for a solution to keep a random order of a user table in the database when clicking the next page button.

Actually I have a database with 1000 users and I want to display 10 users each page (in a memberlist), my query looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY user_id LIMIT 1,10";
```

Now I would like to ORDER BY RAND() and it works, except of course when clicking the next page, then it is shuffled again and it happens sometimes that the same users will be there again.

So my question is about a solution to keep the random order I had on the first page, also on the next pages.

I thought about to set a $_SESSION variable when someone visits the memberlist for the first time with **shuffled numbers from 1 to 1000** in it and then order the members by position in the $_SESSION variable **where a number is equal to a user_id**.

Don't know how this might be possible, but I actually imagine a solution like:

```
$numbers = range(1, 1000);

$shuffled_numbers = shuffle($numbers);

$sort = $_SESSION['random_user_sort'] = $shuffled_numbers;
```

So I will have a mysql query when clicking page two (next page) like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY $sort LIMIT 11,20";
```

Any solution to let it work this way or even better ideas?

Comment: You only have 1000 rows, so just randomize the whole thing and handle the pagination at the application level - so there's only hit on the database.

Comment: Better idea will be don't do this. You'll have to know previous selected users - so what if you have millions of them in table? I.e. that would be slow at least

Comment: Could you please explain what is your goal from the user perspective. I mean what exactly do you want to do as far as business logic is concerned and not only how you are going to achieve it technically. I suspect that what you want to achieve might have an easier solution that will scale more.

Comment: I don't want that always the same users appear on the first page.

Comment: @Strawberry: Loading all 1000 rows at once and sorting them by random actually needs up to 5 seconds until everything is loaded, so I am looking for max display 10 members per request but keeping the random order from the first page on all next pages on all next pages, so no member will appear twice or more.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo: Yes, that's why I want to only save up to 1000 random members displaying at all in that list, even there are more, but to lower the requests and loading time, I want to split these 1000 members into several pages (10 members each page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RAND()` function does not really generate random numbers but what's called *pseudo* random numbers: numbers are calculated with a deterministic formula and they're just intended to *look* random. To calculate a new number, you take the previous one and apply the formula to it, and that's how we get *different* output with a deterministic function: by using different *input*.

The initial number we use is known as *seed*. If you [have a look at the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) you'll see that  `RAND()` has an optional argument:

> `RAND(), RAND(N)`
>
> Returns a random floating-point value v in the range 0 <= v < 1.0. **If
>   a constant integer argument N is specified, it is used as the seed
>   value, which produces a repeatable sequence of column values**

You've probably figured out by now where I want to go:

```
mysql> SELECT language_id, name FROM language ORDER BY RAND(33);
+-------------+----------+
| language_id | name     |
+-------------+----------+
|           3 | Japanese |
|           1 | English  |
|           4 | Mandarin |
|           6 | German   |
|           5 | French   |
|           2 | Italian  |
+-------------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT language_id, name FROM language ORDER BY RAND(33);
+-------------+----------+
| language_id | name     |
+-------------+----------+
|           3 | Japanese |
|           1 | English  |
|           4 | Mandarin |
|           6 | German   |
|           5 | French   |
|           2 | Italian  |
+-------------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

P.S. The manual is not explicit about the seed range (it just says *integer*), you might need some extra research (or just some quick testing).

Comment: Perfect, this helped me to understand and I know now what to do to keep the order on all next pages. Thanks!